# IDL file incompatibility with vS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, idl

I've migrated COM projects from VS2013 to VC2010 then encountered into one issue. In VC10 few method's signature is changed so header file generated is compatible with VC10 but not with VS13.

HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *QueryInterface )(

```
        IFileStr * This,

        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,

        /* [annotation][iid_is][out] */ 

        __RPC__deref_out  void **ppvObject);
```

In the third parameter "__RPC__deref_out" is getting added

and the one generated using VS2013 is like,

HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *QueryInterface )(

```
        IFileStr * This,

        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,

        /* [iid_is][out] */

        __COM_Outptr  void **ppvObject);
```

Can any one suggest?

Comment: __RPC__deref_out is an entirely normal SAL annotation.  Only guess is that you are using the wrong Windows SDK version if the compiler complains about it.

Comment: We tried changing the compiler also ,but still getting same

Comment: That doesn't help us help you.  You can put the problem by writing `#define __RPC__deref_out` before the #include.